# Data cleaning in python-pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a column in pandas DataFrame which reads as follows

`“percent: 71.3456789%”`  How can I clean it to stay with a column reading `“70%”`

I tried using replace as follows "`df.str.replace("width:95.612899266253%;", "95.612899266253%").` The error I am getting is syntax error

How can i solve it

Comment: Hey John, try removing the % sign too that should sort you out. also, please post a minimal example with an expected output. also it would help if you posted your sytnax error..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to get just the numerical value out of the string and perform the rounding on just that.

The regex I used has three groups:

1. the "percent: ",
2. the numerical value,
3. the "%".

`.str.replace` then needs to be passed the `regex=True` argument.

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(["percent: 71.3456789%"],columns=["pct"])

>>> df
                    pct
0  percent: 71.3456789%

repl = lambda m: m.groups(0)[0] + str(round(float(m.groups(0)[1]),0)) + m.groups(0)[2]

simple_decimal = re.compile(r'(percent: )(\d*.\d+)(%)')

>>> df.pct.str.replace(simple_decimal,repl,regex=True)
0    percent: 71.0%
```

Comment: Nice one,will definitely be using this